# Fill in a slice of a list with certain value without allocating new objects

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, micropython

Is there any way to modify python list through slice with only one value without memory allocations?

Something like that:

```
b = range(10)
b[2:5] = 1
```

The problem here is that about memory. I do not want to allocate new objects, because I work with MicroPython on embedded system and unnecessary allocations will affect performance. So should I use cycle or there is more elegant way?

However, I am not really sure about how memory allocations work in python. I have read that Python is smart and allocates variables in stack as well as in heap depending on their usage. Therefore I can not say if:

```
b = range(10)
b[2:5] = [1]*3
```

will create a bit of a work for a garbage collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was naturally better to ask MicroPython developers about that. So I have done that and revealed many interesting things.

```
b[2:5] = [1]*3
```

does allocate new object.
Even

```
for i in range(x, y):
    b[i] = 1
```

allocates memory by `range` call. Though I expected that this case is treated individually to optimize code. Especially if we are talking about python for embedded systems.

Therefore I suppose the most efficient way to do that is using `while` cycle.

```
x = x1
while x < x2:
    b[x] = 1
    x += 1
```

Comment: Was your discussion with the developers on a public forum and if so can you link to it please? I'm struggling to understand your examples because as far as I can see trying to assign to an element or slice of `b` should fail with a `TypeError`.

Comment: @nekomatik you are right, it raises type error, just read the answer more attentively. Assigning element to a slice explains how I would like to do it. But as far as I can not, I search for another way.

Comment: If `b` is a list not an iterable, e.g. `b = list(range(10))`, then e.g. `b[2:5] = [1]*3` will work. If you want to know how to avoid memory allocations in MicroPython though, the MicroPython forum will be the best place to ask.

Comment: @nekomatic the answer describes why using while cycle is the best way to do that in MicroPython.